# show that S is simply connected where complement of S is topologist's sin curve in complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

suppose $S^{c} =\left\{x+yi: 0<x\leq1, y = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right\}\cup \{iy: -1\leq y < \infty\}$. In my complex analysis book definition of simply connected is [image]

My question is that how can I construct $\gamma(t)$ for any $\gamma(0) = \left(x_0, \sin\left(\frac{1}{x_0}\right)\right)$?

Comment: Does $\tilde{D}$ refer to the complement of $D$ in $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: @SolubleFish yes it is complement of D in the complex plane.

Comment: Then your book's definition feels very weird to me. It seems to imply that any set whose complement is dense is simply connected, which is not the case with the usual definitions.

Comment: it is Back and Newman's complex analysis book. However, if we use the continuous curve in the definition how can I connect it to origin and go to infinity? Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is very far from the normal definition of "simply connected." weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z_0 = (x_0, \sin(\frac{1}{x_0}))$ it is easy: Define $\gamma(t) = (x_0+t, \sin(\frac{1}{x_0+t}))$. This is a curve **in** $S^c$, thus (a) is satisfied. (b) and (c) are obvious.

For $z_0 = (0, y_0)$ it is just a little more difficult. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $y_0 \in [-1,1]$, there exists $t_0 \ge 0$ such that $\sin t_0 = y_0$. Hence also $\sin t_k = y_0$ where $t_k = t_0 + 2k\pi$. Hence $\sin(\frac{1}{x_k}) = y_0$ for $x_k = \frac{1}{t_k}$. But $x_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Therefore $x_{k_0} < \epsilon$ for some sufficiently large $k_0$. Now define
$$\gamma(t) = \begin{cases} (t,y_0)  & t \le x_{k_0} \\  (t, \sin(\frac{1}{t}))& t \ge x_{k_0}\end{cases} $$
This is well-defined continous map because for $t = x_{k_0}$ both lines produce the same value $(x_{k_0}, y_0)$. (b) and (c) are clearly satisfied. For $t \ge x_{k_0}$ we have $\gamma(t) \in S^c$ and for $t \le x_{k_0}$ we have $d(\gamma(t), S^C) \le d(\gamma(t),(0,y_0) = t \le x_{k_0} < \epsilon$. Thus also (a) is satisfied.

Comment: It is one of the exercises in the book and part of $S^c$ $iy$ goes to infinity why it is bounded? it seems to me it is unbounded.  $S^c$ seems to me closed but unbounded

Comment: You are right, I didn't read your definition of $S^c$ properly. Usually the topologist's sine curve is defined as a compact set. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve. I shall consider how to show that $S$ is simply connected.

Comment: If I can reach origin somehow with a continuos curve from any point, then I can go to infinity but I could not show that.

Comment: thank you very much